# how to read array data with firebase and flutter to retrieve active subjects?

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, document

I'm looking to retrieve the contents of an array of maps (the 'subjects', below) within documents in firebase to populate a ListView, using flutter.

For illustration, my documents' structure can be simplified to:

- course_name
- subjects (an array of map)

  - subject_id
  - subject_name
  - subject_is_active

There will be one document per course.

I am a relative newcomer here, so I've tried to adapt snippets of code found on various sites. I feel that I'm 'almost' there, but can't quite get it sorted out!

There are two things I try to understand:

1. how to query my collection of documents to find only the active subjects (subject_is_active == true) for a given course (course_name = 'my key value')
2. how to ascertain the number of active subjects for the given course, so that I can set the correct ItemCount for the ListView that I'm trying to populate.

My code:

```
 Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    return ListTile(
        title: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              document['subject_name'].toString(),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text('is active'
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
              StreamBuilder(
                  stream:
                  Firestore.instance.collection('courses').where('course_name', isEqualTo: 'test course').snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('loading...');
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemExtent: 80.0,
                      itemCount: itemBuilder: (context, index) => _buildListItem(
                          context, snapshot.data.documents[index])
                    );
                  }),

            )));
  }
```

Comment: reformulate your question tag to make it obvious what the problem is. Fixed your code indentation. Stuff like: "I am trying" in the question tag gets removed.

Comment: hi zf007 - is that better ?  thanks for fixing the code indentation too :)

Comment: Much better... dots are now on the 'i'. Hope you get luck and someone can help you out. (from review).